# How can I have a transparent overlay and center with flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a block element with a background image. I am attempting to:

- Add a transparent gradient overlay on top of a background image
- Center another block element using flexbox,

I **have already achieved both of these independently of each other**, see the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVdmKP) as well as the images and code below.

Using the transparent overlay (with the child block HTML removed):

[image]

Centering the child block (with the overlay CSS removed):

[image]

However when I try and combine the effects, the flexbox stops working and the overlay is missing around the child block [image]

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p>title goes here</p>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  background: url("http://msue.anr.msu.edu/uploads/images/forest.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.71);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container p {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24pt;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #dc4225, #292484);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

*How can I get the semitransparent overlay overlay and the flexbox happening at the same time?*

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `.container:after`, change `position: relative` to `position: absolute`.

**Live, working example:**

```css
.container {
  background: url("http://msue.anr.msu.edu/uploads/images/forest.jpg");
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.71);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container p {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24pt;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container:after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #dc4225, #292484);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>title goes here</p>
</div>
```

Codepen Version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpqxoo

Comment: Nice - and great spot! I just found a fix myself but it involved an extra element. This is much better!

Answer (score 1):

In case folks need to set position of the container to absolute like I do:

```
.container {
    @include inline-flex;
    @include flex-direction(column);
    @include align-items(center);
    @include justify-content(center);

    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal;
    z-index: 1;
}

.container::after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

The importance pieces here are `rgba`, and `z-index`. Background image of the container is set dynamically in code, but that isn't relevant here.